# Reflective embeddings outside separation?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, embeddings

One of the known ways to axiomatize ZF is via these two axiom schemata:

**Separation:** $\forall \vec{w} \forall A \exists! x: x=\{y \in A: \phi\}$

**Reflection:** $\forall \vec{w} \exists \alpha: \phi \to \phi^{V_\alpha}$

Now if we add to this a primitive unary function symbol $j$, and stipulate that $j$ is nontrivial elementary embedding of the whole universe to itself, but forbid the use of $j$ in separation and permit it in Reflection.

> What would be the effect of that?

> Would the resulting theory be consistent with choice?

Comment: Regarding your second question, if $j:L\to L$ is elementary (where say $j$ is definable) then $(L,j)$ models the theory plus choice.

Comment: @FarmerS, but why should such $j$ exist.

Comment: I just mean assume there is one. See $0^\#$ (zero sharp).

Comment: Or suppose $k:V\to M$ is elementary, $M$ transitive; then $L^M=L$, so the restriction $j$ of $k$ to $L$ is elementary $L\to L$. I also wanted $j$ to be definable, which can be arranged with more work. But that doesn't really matter; we just need $j$ a class, which follows if $k$ is.